# How to find the averages of any consecutive numbers in a sequence?

Tags: math, average, mean

This is a bit of a math question, but I post it here too because there's a direct practical purpose and it's related to creating a faster algorithm. I want to identify users that use my app on a weekly basis. For each user I can generate a sequence of times of their interactions, and from that I can generate a sequence of the length of time between each interaction.

So given this sequence of lengths of time, how can I find sections of consecutive numbers that have an average of 7 days or less?

As an example, if I had the following sequence: [1, 11, 1, 8, 12]

[1, 11, 1, 8, 12] would be a valid stretch of numbers with an average of 7 or less, but [11, 1, 8, 12] would not be valid. [1, 2, 12] would again be valid.

Ideally, my output for every valid section would be the starting position of the first item and the length of the section. So [1, 11, 1, 8, 12] would be described as [1, 5] and [1, 2, 12] would be described as [3, 3].

There is a brute force, computational approach where I take every item in the sequence as a start point, and calculate the averages of every possible length of following numbers up until the end of the sequence. The number of calculations grows quickly though at a rate of n(n+1)/2 (Imagine for each given sequence of length N finding consecutive sequences of length N, N-1, N-2 etc.)

I ask broadly if there's a more elegant approach that doesn't require a quadratically growing number of individual calculations for means.

Comment: That's not a *set*, its a *sequence* (since order matters).

Comment: Since it is possible for *every* subsequence to meet your criteria, you aren't going to able to avoid the n(n+1)/2.